# Background not displayed

Tags: html

What is wrong with my code \|/ I have copied the code from my other pages that work with the background but this one seems to just be blank. It will display anything but the background.

```
<body background="Music.png" bgproperties="fixed">
```

And before you say it, I have uploaded it in the same folder as the website. Here is my site: http://doomfire106.co.nf/Music.html

Comment: Mind giving us a URL to the page?

Comment: Are sure it is `Music.png` not `music.png`

Comment: Please learn CSS. There is no reason to use those attributes in this century.

Comment: I'd suggest pasting your site code (or at least a dumbed down version) to pastebin or otherwise for us. I suspect some syntax issues somewhere before/after the line you've given us.

Comment: http://doomfire106.co.nf/

Comment: @DoomFire106 — That page doesn't have that code on it, and the background image it does have shows up.

Comment: <body>

<body style="background-image:url('Music.png');">

<br><br>
<font color=White>
<font size=4>
<Table width = 20% border = 0>
<Tr width=50%>
<br><br><br><br>
<tr align = "Left">
 this is only part of it

Comment: No you need to click the http://www.doomfire106.co.nf/Music.html/ instead that was the home page and the background works for that!

Comment: You have two body elements.

Comment: The image you are trying to load is http://www.doomfire106.co.nf/Music.html/Music.png which is an error page (http://www.doomfire106.co.nf/Music.png is also an error page)

Comment: Invalid markup does give odd errors sometimes :)

Comment: well yes because you are trying to view a image as a html page

Comment: We're viewing the file as the server instructs our browsers to view it.

Comment: You might have messed up permissions for this file. Please check if it's set to "read&write" or at least just "read" for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[www.doomfire106.co.nf/Music.html](http://www.doomfire106.co.nf/Music.html) is full of errors according to the W3C [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.doomfire106.co.nf%2FMusic.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0). Most of these are harmless, but the duplicate `<body>` elements is not; remove the extra element. You also have content before your `<body background="WebsiteBack.png">` element; content should be inside the element.

Sending an HTTP request for [www.doomfire106.co.nf/Websiteback.png](http://www.doomfire106.co.nf/Websiteback.png) returns HTTP 500, Internal Server Error, so something is going wrong with your host when requesting that file. Check file permissions of your `Websiteback.png` file; it must have Read and Execute permissions for everyone.

The response looks like a PHP error message; do you have any filters on your site? Is your `WebsiteBack.png` page being generated by PHP?